# R Data.Table With Weights

Tags: r, data.table, summary

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table("STUDENT" = c(1:100),
                  "SAMPLEWEIGHT" = sample(12:99, r = T, 100),
"LABEL1" = sample(1:2, r = T, 100),
"LABEL3" = sample(1:3, r = T, 100),
"CAT"=sample(0:1,r = T, 100),
"FOX"=sample(0:1,r = T, 100),
"DOG"=sample(0:1,r = T, 100),
"MOUSE"=sample(0:1,r = T, 100),
"BIRD"=sample(0:1,r = T, 100))

dataWANT = data.frame("LABEL1" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                                            "LABEL3" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                                            "CAT_N" = NA,
                                            "CAT_PER" = NA,
                                            "FOX_N" = NA,
                                            "FOX_PER" = NA,
                                            "DOG_N" = NA,
                                            "DOG_PER" = NA,
                                            "MOUSE_N" = NA,
                                            "MOUSE_PER" = NA,
                                            "BIRD_N" = NA,
                                            "BIRD_PER" = NA)
```

I have a data.table call it data, and am attempting to try and summarize the student data like what is shown in dataWANT.

in dataWANT the columns that have _N at the end is just the count of values in the column that equals to 1 for each LABEL1 and LABEL3 combination so a total of 6 groups.

in dataWANT the columns that have _PER at the end is the weighted proportion of the groups that have ones in their column.

Comment: Do you need `data[, c(setNames(lapply(.SD, sum), paste0(names(.SD), "_N")), setNames(lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x == 1, SAMPLEWEIGHT)), paste0(names(.SD), "_PER"))),.(LABEL1, LABEL3), .SDcols = CAT:BIRD]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table` would be to group by 'LABEL1', 'LABEL3', specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, get the `sum` (as it binary columns) by looping over the `.SD` and concatenate with the `weighted.mean` based on the 'SAMPLEWEIGHT' column

```
library(data.table)
data[, c(setNames(lapply(.SD, sum), paste0(names(.SD), "_N")), 
  setNames(lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x == 1, SAMPLEWEIGHT)), 
     paste0(names(.SD), "_PER"))),.(LABEL1, LABEL3), .SDcols = CAT:BIRD]
```

Comment: @akun also if you have a chance to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611000/r-summarize-collapsed-data-table/61611259?noredirect=1#comment108991548_61611259

Comment: @bvowe Please do check the values for weightedd.mean

Comment: This would be the `dplyr` equivalent (which is out of scope of the question, but still interesting to compare to the `data.table` approach):
`data %>% 
  group_by(LABEL1, LABEL3) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(CAT:BIRD), list(N = ~ sum(.),
                                    PER = ~ weighted.mean(. == 1, SAMPLEWEIGHT)))`