# R Data.Table Compare Groups Simulteanous

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table("LABEL1" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
"LABEL3" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
"CAT"=runif(6),
"FOX"=runif(6),
"DOG"=runif(6),
"MOUSE"=runif(6),
"BIRD"=runif(6))
```

I wish to execute t-test for variables CAT:BIRD, these are proportions. I want to compare these groups:

LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=2 gets compared to LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=1

LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=3 gets compared to LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=1

LABEL1=2 & LABEL3=2 gets compared to LABEL1=2 & LABEL3=1

LABEL1=2 & LABEL3=3 gets compared to LABEL1=2 & LABEL3=1

and I hope to store P VALUE like such:

[image]

Comment: We need clarification on your question. First, how do we define the comparisons? There are 16 possible combinations in `data`, but you only want 4?  Second, how do you want to keep up with what comparison has been performed? Your expected output only has the first group. Third, you request `P-VALUE` 5 times per row, but `chisq.test` results in only 1 p.value. Do you want the same value repeated 5 times?

Comment: @ian campbell thank you very much. the goal is to test if there are differences in the variables CAT:BIRD. I wish to compare all groups to either LABEL=1 & LABEL3=2 or LABEL1=2 & LABEL3=2. For example say you have 6 groups 1:6. And you want to know, are there differences in the distribution of the variables CAT:BIRD for group 2 compared to group 1; for group 3 compared to group 1, and so forth. I hope this helps to provide clarification

Comment: @ian campbell so the first P-VALUE under 'CAT' is the P-VALUE of comparing the proportion for CAT among the group with LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=2 compared to LABEL1=1 & LABEL3=1. does that make sense?

Comment: I am not a statistician, but `chisq.test` tests that the frequencies of CAT, FOX, DOG, MOUSE, and BIRD deviate from the expected value. This p-value has a single value for the test and thus isn't different for CAT or FOX. Perhaps you need to as your question on [CrossValidiated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)?